# How can i name with minecraft icons (potions or blocks texture)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In xisumavoid latest video he shows that he renamed his villagers with blocks and items textures. He later also makes a sign with the hero of the village effect icon.
Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! May I ask what mediums you would like to use to achieve this effect? Or is your query simply for what the medium is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done using the [Custom Roleplay data pack](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/customization/custom-roleplay-data-datapack).

The datapack by itself only streamlines adding custom texture variants to pre-existing items through a resource pack; it's still up to you to create said texture pack (containing the variant textures or models) and then spawn the variant items into the world using commands (giving the "base" items custom NBT tags that identify the variant.) The process of creating a texture pack in general goes way beyond the scope of this answer; the modification necessary is adding an overrides predicate "custom_model_data" with numerical ID, which determines which variant the item is; '0' is the 'default look', and anything else will be your special variants. Spawning the item looks like `/give @s apple{CustomModelData:1}`.

The video explains the process in detail: